# Why are people interested in square-free values?

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading an article by Dan Carmon on square-free values of large polynomials over the rational function field and became interested in the question

> What is the use of square-free values? Who 'started' investigating them and why? What was the use (if there was any) back in the day and is there any use now?

I found it very difficult to find extra information this. Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What is the use of art? What is the use of music?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, for me art and music is a way of expressing emotions. Although it doesn't need to be the case, I could imagine that there is some application for investigating square-free numbers as well (for instance Cryptography or something?). My question might be better formulated as, is there a field in which we use square-free values?

Comment: I believe (I'm an aficionado) that the answer below tell you that square-free integers are important because these encode one of the most important mysteries in mathematics, the Riemann hypothesis. On the other hand also are related to another mystery, also related to the distribution of prime factors, the abc conjecture (you can to read information about this last open problem from *It’s As Easy As abc* by Andrew Granville and Thomas J. Tucker from the [NOTICES of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/notices) Vol. 49, N,10 NOVEMBER 2002). I add this comment as companion of previous answer, good luck.

Comment: I add also that in YouTube from the official channel **UConn Math** there is a colloquium of great quality dedicated to the abc conjecture. That is *What is the abc conjecture?* by Keith Conrad, from the University of Connecticut (2012). I am adding this last comment as reference for all users because is showed also theory and relationships about polynomials and diophantine equations. Isn't required a response, and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question, but it discusses related matters.

The Mobius function, $\mu(n)$, is defined to be 1 if $n$ is squarefree and has an even number of prime divisors, $-1$ if $n$ is squarefree and has an odd number of prime divisors, and 0 if $n$ is not squarefree. Thus, $\sum_{n\le N}|\mu(n)|$ counts the number of squarefree values of the polynomial $f(x)=x$ up to $N$, so there's a connection to squarefree values of polynomials.

Now, $\mu(n)$ turns out to be a very well-connected function in Number Theory. It shows up in the Mobius Inversion Formula, which says if $g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$ then $f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)g(n/d)$. And it is intimately related to the Riemann Zeta function, via the equation ${1\over\zeta(s)}=\sum_1^{\infty}{\mu(n)\over n^s}$.

So, if you are interested in Number Theory, then you are interested in the Mobius function, and if you are interested in the Mobius function, you are interested in squarefree values.